# Webstorm: save only open tab vs. save all tabs?

Tags: webstorm

I'm new to webstorm since I started my latest job, and I'm finding some features difficult to adapt to. In particular, the fact that it forces you to save all open changes in all tabs at once is problematic.

I have a somewhat organic method of development, swapping between HTML and LESS frequently until I reach a point where I want to save the files and see what my work has accomplished. Whenever I save an open HTML doc, it saves the incomplete LESS that I just left mid-thought as well, and pops up a compiler error. Is there any way to force webstorm to only save the active tab?

(Aside: Please don't suggest I adjust my mindset or my workflow to adapt to my environment. Not only is that poor usability, it would require me to override an instinct that was developed for good reason: when you reach a milestone, you save it lest something bad happen. Leaving an unsaved doc open makes my eye twitch.)

Comment: See [this discussion](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98513). The feature was added and will be available in the next version.

Comment: are you using file watcher to compile LESS? If so, turning 'Immediate file synchronization' option off for your watcher will probably help to get rid of compiler errors on incomplete LESS: when it's off, watcher will only start on explicit save (File | Save All) or when you move focus from WebStorm (upon frame deactivation).

Comment: @lena unfortunately no, I'm using codekit to compile all my meta-css - and it's viciously automatic

Comment: If you don't already know, but disabling auto save may help you from what I understood of your question...

Answer (score 5):

This has been (sort of) implemented in v7.0. You'll need to dig into *Settings* > *Menus and Toolbars* to add "Save Document" to the program menu, and *Settings* > *Keymap* if you want to assign a keyboard shortcut (and disable Ctrl+S for Save All).

You may also want to tick "Mark modified tabs with asterisk" under *Settings* > *Editor* > *Editor Tabs*.

Note: You will **not** be warned if you exit without saving your changes.